# Behavior of Dirichlet L-functions at the edge of the critical strip

Tags: analytic-number-theory, l-functions, riemann-hypothesis

Given a Dirichlet L-function $L(\chi, s)$ of a primitive character $\chi$, what is the asymptotic behavior of $L(\chi, 1+it)$ for real $t$? I am looking for as many answers for the same question. This includes answers that do or do not rely on GRH. $\textbf{I am also interested in particular cases}$: explicit primitive $\chi$ that are uglier/prettier than usual. Here are some specific questions I'm desperate to have answered:

Is $|L(\chi, 1+it)| < ct^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c>0$?

Is $|L(\chi, 1+it)| < c\log(t)^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c>0$?

It is known that $L(\chi, 1+it)$ is non-vanishing. This gives a trivial lower bound:

$|L(\chi, 1+it)| > 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Flipping the inequalities in the questions above gives lower bounds for $|L(\chi, 1+it)|$. Is anything known about the validity of those inequalities?

If nothing of this sort is known, even under the assumption of GRH, what is the rumored behavior?

Some background: I'm trying to develop techniques that will allow me to prove non-vanishing of $L(\chi, 1+it)$. I understand that this is well known but I am interested in an approach that will tell me more about the nature of $L(\chi, s)$ at the edge of the critical strip. I'm here because I've given up and I'm having trouble finding sources that would answer these questions.

Comment: It's known that $L(1 + it,\chi) \ll_q \log(|t| + 3)$ unconditionally and $L(1 + it,\chi) \ll_q (\log \log (|t| + 9))$ under GRH. On the flipside, there is a constant $C > 0$ such that there exists a sequence of real numbers $t$ with $|t| \to \infty$ for which $|L(1 + it,\chi)| \geq C (\log \log (|t| + 9))$ (I can't remember off the top of my head whether this is unconditional or under GRH). This is all in Montgomery-Vaughan's book.

Comment: to complement @Peter answer- unconditionally $L(1 + it,\chi) \ll_q ((\log t) (\log \log t))^{3/4}, t >t_0$ since one can apply Lemmas $6.12, 6.13$ in Titchmars RZ bible to $t \log (x+a),  0<a<1$ and use the decomposition of $L$ into a sum of Riemann-Hurwitz polynomials ($\chi (a)\sum_{n << t^b} /(n+a)^s$) for $a=h/q, h=1,..q$ with good error precisely the way the above result for zeta is proven in Theorem $6.14$; similarly, it shouldn't be too hard to adapt the proof of Theorem $8.5$ to show $|L(1 + it_n,\chi)| \geq C (\log \log t_n), t_n \to \infty$ using Kronecker approximation theorem etc

Comment: @PeterHumphries and Conrad Thanks for the resources. I will immediately look into them. Some background: For arbitrary primitive $\chi$, I was able to come up with the logarithmic upper bound $|L(1+it, \chi)| < C \log(t+1) +\epsilon(t)$ with $C>0$ and $\epsilon(t) =o(1)$.  I know I'm not crazy now. As for the lower bound sequence thing... I'm in disbelief. I am working with the quadratic characters and my hunch was that they did not grow . Is the character supposed to be fixed in that sequence????

Comment: And what does $<<$ mean